# Acer Aspire 4750 cannot turn on wifi after switch to Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux-mint, acer-aspire

I installed Linux Mint 19 in my Laptop Acer Aspire 4750 but the wifi doesn't work.  I found my wireless hard blocked. I tried to unblocked it using rfkill.

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Is there a hardware switch, or keyboard (function) combination of keys you have to press to activate wifi?

Comment: Yes I tried with the keyboard combination, and it doesn't work

Comment: It's the right button combination? I didn't have much luck finding your exact model, but similar Acers seem to use Fn-F3. Any messages show up in dmesg or the syslog when you press those buttons? I think I found what looks like a solution on a Linux Mint forum (you should always try searching there for Linux Mint problems FYI)

Answer (score 0):

From a web search, I found https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=273356 which appears to list a solution of adding

```
blacklist acer-wmi
```

to your `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file, then rebooting (or you might be able to use a combination of `rmmod`, `modprobe`, `lsmod` to remove the acer-wmi module without rebooting, but I'm not sure if you might need to replace it with something else).

Here's the entire post FYI:

> ### Wifi Not Enabled Acer Aspire 4750
>
> by sabirulla » Sun Jul 15, 2018 8:18 am
>
> ~$ rfkill list all
>   0: phy0: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: yes
>   ~$ sudo rmmod acer-wmi
>
> add below line at the end of the file :   /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
>
> blacklist acer-wmi
>
> Then restart the system.
>   ~$ rfkill list all
>   0: phy0: Wireless LAN
>   Soft blocked: no
>   Hard blocked: no

Comment: root@jose-Aspire-4750:/home/jose# rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: bash: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf: Permission denied